# A bit of advice on Cassandra vs. MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, nosql, cassandra

I asked a question on here a couple of days ago and got some really good answers, i'm thinking about doing a facebook style website with profiles, bio's, etc, and asked whether i should use mysql, the answers were to use Cassandra because its much better. I'm just asking is this what everyone would suggest, its just i know mysql fairly well and would it be a completely stupid move on my part to use mysql over Cassandra (which i hadnt even heard of until 2 days ago)

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go for MySQL. Cassandra will make development hard, it still lacks tools, tutorials, etc. And it's rapidly changing, so you'll have to change your code as well.

Take a look [at this article](http://techblog.bozho.net/?p=232) - it explains why I think it's not yet the time for regular projects to go for Cassandra.

In case your application sky-rockets and needs more scalability than MySQL provides, then you'll have enough people to handle the transition to Cassandra. Just abstract your [Data access layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_layer) so that you can later switch without changing the rest of the code.

Update: Note the date of this answer. It is by definition going to get out of date, so check if there are already good tools, tutorials, etc.

Comment: Just an update for future readers - this answer was accurate in 2010, but coming up on mid 2013, it is no longer the case as the author noted would occur. Companies like Facebook, Twitter and Netflix all use Cassandra, and in my opinion, is a better solution than MySQL for large deployments. If you are looking for something small, stick with MySQL.

Comment: Jonathan: your answer is now out of date. RAM prices have decreased exponentially, making traditional databases the best choice for most projects. Facebook has stopped using Cassandra, as has Twitter. RAM will continue to become cheaper, and your time will always be valuable, so my bet is that this answer will become increasingly valid for the years to come.